# Clojure - Calculate with big numbers

Tags: clojure, overflow, integer-overflow

I want to calculate `!1000` in clojure, how can I do this without getting a integer-overflow exception?

My factorial code is right now: `(reduce * (range 1 1001))`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use the `*'` operator which supports arbitrary precision by automatically promoting the result to BigInt in case it would overflow:

```
(reduce *' (range 1 1001))
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a bit easier and cleaner.

Comment: What are the pros / cons of doing it this way instead of @Hamza's way?

Answer (score 6):

Put N at the end of the number which makes it a bigint,

```
(reduce * (range 1N 1001N))
```

Answer (score 2):

Coerce the parameters to `clojure.lang.BigInt`

```
(reduce * (range (bigint 1) (bigint 1001)))
```

I.e. if you are working with an third-party library that doesn't use `*'`

```
(defn factorial' [n]
   (factorial (bigint n)))
```