# clojure: Compute Factorial of number using defmulti and defmethod

Tags: clojure

I tried to compute factorial through defmulti and defmethod.

```
(defmulti factorial identity)

(defmethod factorial 0 [_] 1)

(defmethod factorial :default [num]
  (* num (factorial (dec num))))
```

It works fine for small numbers

```
(-> 10 factorial) ;;3628800

(-> 2 factorial) ;; 2
```

it shows Integer Overflow Exception for factorial 40

```
(-> 40 factorial)

ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow
```

My curiosity is

How can we compute factorial for Big Numbers using defmulti and defmethod?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure - Calculate with big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826649/clojure-calculate-with-big-numbers)

Comment: minor nagging: `(-> x factorial)` is way harder to read than just `(factorial x)`. Threading macros are great, but using them for everything is overkill

Answer (score 2):

Clojure's implementation of number types builds on the host platform's number types. [Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181602/8123584) works when you define the *arbitrary size* flag `N`, because the underlying number type changes on the JVM.

```
(type 10)  ;=> java.lang.Long
(type 10N) ;=> clojure.lang.BigInt
```

`clojure.lang.BigInt` [uses either `java.math.BigInteger` or a Java `long` as the underlying type](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/BigInt.java), depending on the bit size of the number.

On a different host, the Javascript engine of a browser, both types are JavaScript's native `Number`s. The `factorial` function gives a result up to 170 in ClojureScript. It does not throw when overflowing, but returns the JavaScript number value [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity):

```
(factorial 170)  ; => 7.257415615307994e+306
(factorial 170N) ; => 7.257415615307994e+306
(factorial 171N) ; => Infinity
```

**Update:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826898/8123584) (pointed out by [@cske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630569/cske)) gives a neat solution to use the `*'` operator, which bumps up the number type in case it would overflow:

```
(defmethod factorial :default [num]
  (*' num (factorial (dec num))))

(factorial 40) ; => 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000N
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it

```
(-> 40N factorial) ;;815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000N
```